# Unity C#: Adding Code to Transform Enemy Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on the following script in Unity C#, which is assigned to an enemy. I would like to add code that enables the enemy to move up and down, or side to side, but am having trouble getting anything to work. Advice on adding this functionality is very appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damageRadius = 0.5f;
    public int meleeDamage = 200;

    [HideInInspector]
    Entity entityScript;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        entityScript = GetComponent<Entity>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckForPlayerAndDamage();
        CheckForHealthAndDie();
    }


    void CheckForPlayerAndDamage()
    {
        var colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, damageRadius);
        foreach (var collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Entity>().ApplyDamage(meleeDamage);
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, damageRadius);
    }

    public void CheckForHealthAndDie()
    {
        if(entityScript.isDead)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt and the problem you have with said attempt? The provided code doesn't show anything that should invoke movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damageRadius = 0.5f;
    public int meleeDamage = 200;
    
    // new
    private Transform player;
    private float speed = 10f;

    [HideInInspector]
    Entity entityScript;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        entityScript = GetComponent<Entity>();
        
        // new
        player = GameObject.Find("PlayerNameInInspector");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckForPlayerAndDamage();
        CheckForHealthAndDie();
        
        //new 
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards( transform.position, player.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime );
        transform.LookAt( player.transform.position, Vector3.up );
    }


    void CheckForPlayerAndDamage()
    {
        var colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, damageRadius);
        foreach (var collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Entity>().ApplyDamage(meleeDamage);
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, damageRadius);
    }

    public void CheckForHealthAndDie()
    {
        if(entityScript.isDead)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```